# How can I add rich text editor with PrimeFaces and Java EE?

Tags: jsf, rich-text-editor

How can I add rich text editor with PrimeFaces and ava EE? I want to create edittext with JSF, functions are: saved the file, upload.

Comment: *"Another question .."*  What followed that is not a question, and SO is not a help-desk, so each thread should be limited to one answerable, clear and specific question. `click for details` So.. what message did you see when you clicked it?

Comment: I removed the second question. Please ask one question per Question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PrimeFaces Editor component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/editor.xhtml) to provide a rich text editing capability.

You might also want to take a look at the [PrimeFaces Extensions ckEditor component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/ckEditor/basicUsage.jsf) if the PrimeFaces Editor doesn't meet your needs.

If you need to upload a file first then take a look at the [PrimeFaces FileUpload component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml).

Comment: Let's say I save the content of the primefaces textEditor on a database. When I bring it back up on the UI, will the textEditor remember its format? (Like bullets, bold, italics, etc.)